# Datetime.parse issue..?

Tags: apex, datetime

I am convert date/time in string to datetime apex using datetime.parse().But it is is subtracting 1 min..

```
 String s1='5/23/2013';
 String t1='10:00 PM';
 String s2=s1+' '+t1;
 Datetime d=Datetime.parse(s2);

 Event ev= new Event();
 ev.Subject=meet.subject__c;
 ev.ownerid=userinfo.getuserid();
 ev.StartDateTime=datetime.now().adddays(1);
 ev.EndDateTime=d;
```

When i am saving this record to salesforce it is subtracting 1 min less.. i dont know why..?
my saved record is showing 9:59 PM

Answer (score 1):

To help sort your problem out, I'd suggest you add some system assert or debug statements to your code.

```
String s2=s1+' '+t1;
SystemAssert(s2, '5/23/2013 10:00 PM');
```

or

```
String s2=s1+' '+t1;
SystemDebug(s2);
```

which won't stop the execution, but will give you the value of s2 before parsing

I'd also recommend moving the

```
Datetime d=Datetime.parse(s2);
```

into your Event creation statement as:

```
ev.EndDateTime=Datetime.parse(s2);
```

and again, I'd add a SystemDebug(s2) here to see what the value is

Comment: thanks mate for replying...i tried but its not working...its still saving 1 min earlier...i dont know why..??

Comment: Did the system debugs show it as being the correct value in both places?